# Android - onGlobalLayout is not called by ViewTreeObserver

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-viewtreeobserver

I have a headache in current Android project. I want to detect the changing of the current page. For example, there is a **TextView** to display device time, which is updated per second. How to detect this change? I searched a lot on SO (thanks SO), but none works for me.

More information: I don't use standard Activity to create page. My way is:
All widgets are created into a View object which is then used to create a container object. After that, I just handle this container to draw on a canvas with a **VSYNC** callback **[Choreographer.FrameCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.FrameCallback.html)** periodically.

Indeed, it works to draw. All are ok. Except: I want to draw **canvas** only when the page's content changed. So back to my beginning question, how to detect this "changing" event? I am sure there is some kind of callback to handle this problem. I used the following solution, but **[onGlobalLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)** is not called when textview's text changed.

```
CanvasAppViewContainer container;//CanvasAppViewContainer extends AbsoluteLayout
LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)getService().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     

View view = li.inflate(resourceId, null);//passed a correct the layout id
container = new CanvasAppViewContainer(getService(), view, getWidth(), getHeight(), getSurface());
rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView); //root element of layout
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("test", "onGlobalLayout");
    }
});
```

**BTW:** Even if I register the view tree observer for the textview, onGlobalLayout is still not called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`onGlobalLayout()` is only called when the *layout* changes. When you want to detect a change in the *text* use [`TextView.addTextChangedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: Thanks. Actually, if register view tree observer for textview, when text changed, onGlobalLayout() is also invoked in normal activity.

Comment: Maybe the changing of the text causes the TextView to change it's size, which triggers OnGlobalLayout() in your "normal" acivity?

Comment: I just set the same text repeatedly.

Comment: Did  `TextView.addTextChangedListener()` work for your custom view?

Comment: I didn't verify it. I think it will work after change text in TextView. But it is not that I want.